# (Excel) Conditional Formatting based on Adjacent Cell Value

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting in Excel on a range of cells, based on the adjacent cell's value, to achieve something like this:

[image: Expense Conditional Formatting]

The goal is to highlight values in Column B (Actual Expense) red if the value is greater than it's adjacent value in column C (Expected Expense). I've followed a number of tutorials that said to apply conditional formatting by selecting **Conditional Formatting>New Rules>Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format** then applying a rule =$B4>$C4 which would format the 'Actual' cell red if it were greater than the 'Expected' cell. This works great for one cell, but not so well when I attempt to apply this to a range of cells. I've used the format painter as well as editing the rule to be applied over a range of cells (i.e. $B$2:$B$5) as shown below but it only bases the formatting on the initial formula (if B4 is greater than C4) and everything undesirably turns red. 
[image]

I'd rather not make individual rules for every row. Is there a way to consolidate this into one rule?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to take out the $ signs before the row numbers in the formula....and the row number used in the formula should correspond to the **first** row of data, so if you are applying this to the ("applies to") range $B$2:$B$5 it must be this formula

`=$B2>$C2`

by using that "relative" version rather than your "absolute" one Excel (implicitly) adjusts the formula for each row in the range, as if you were copying the formula down

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for explaining it clearly. The extra $ values and not starting the formula from the initial cell was messing up the conditional format. It works perfect now.

Comment: Hi guys, was wondering if let say you have multiple columns (i.e. Actual 2 and Actual 3 on columns D and E) that would also corresponds to Expected, how should I change the "formula" and "applies to"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if maybe it's a difference in Excel version but this question is 6 years old and the accepted answer didn't help me so this is what I figured out:

Under Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules:

1. Make a new rule with "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
2. Make your rule, but put a dollar sign only in front of the letter: `$A2<$B2`
3. Under "Applies to", Manually select the second column (It would not work for me if I changed the value in the box, it just kept snapping back to what was already there), so it looks like `$B$2:$B$100` (assuming you have 100 rows)

This worked for me in Excel 2016.