# Conditonal Formatting Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

This seems like a simple conditional formatting question and i hope it is for many.

I have two columns. Column 'I' with a reference value and column 'J' with a user value. I also have 4000 rows of data!

I would like to simply use conditional formatting in each row to identify if Column 'J' has a value equal too or less than column 'I'. If true, i want to highlight the cell in column 'J' green. If false, leave formatting as it is.

I have been chasing an answer on this for three hours and cannot find any resolution as you simply cannot copy and paste the formatting down the column in excel by dragging of similar. I can copy and paste formatting from one row to another but this is not a solution with 4000 rows. I have adjusted relative and absolute references.

Any links to supporting ways to do this would be great.

[image]

[Here is a sample copy of the file with reduced data](https://ufile.io/7jmuy)

Comment: I think following post will help you. [(Excel) Conditional Formatting based on Adjacent Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723801/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-adjacent-cell-value)

Comment: Thanks Lighthouselk...i have seen similar posts but it doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select `J3` and go to Conditional Formatting, then select `Format only cells that contain` then select `Cell Value` and `less than`, then type `=I3` (remove all `$` as these are absolute cell references).  This much it looks like you have already done.

Once you click `OK` you would then select your target rule and change the range of cells  in `Applies to`.  For instance, you would add `=$J$3:$J$4000`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this dosn't resolve the issue my end. I3 remains the reference for all rows once i extend the Applies to range. IF you can get it working in the supplied file, that would be very helpful.

Comment: In the example you posted I got it working with adding `Sheet1!$J$3:$J$16` to the `Applies to` range.  In the sample you posted, it seems that the two values that are subjected to the conditional formatting are both less than I3, which may be why you think it is only referencing I3.  In fact, they're referencing the adjacent columns.

Comment: timotaoh...you are correct. I was expected to see the reference update, like when you see the reference update if you copy and paste the formatting from one cell to another. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
=$I2
```

Here dolor sign has significant as you are checking value column wise means in a column top to bottom.

[image]