# Highlight exceeding limit in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
line    customer product OrderQty TotalQty
1        A        11111    5        10
2        B        11111    5        10
3        c        11111    5        10
4        A        22222    5        20
5        B        22222    5        20
6        C        22222    5        20
```

I have a table as shown above.

I want to to highlight the lines when OrderQty is bigger than TotalQty for a product.

OrderQty represents the number of units requested for in that order, TotalQty represents total units available to fulfil all orders.

In this example, I want to highlight lines 1,2,3 as product 11111 OrderQty 5+5+5=15 is bigger than TotalQty 10.

Is there a way to automate this in VBA? I suspect using Sumifs but I can't wrap my head around..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kyle, have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723801/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-adjacent-cell-value. I think your answer is there if without VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Range("A:E").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
Range("C1:C7").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True
Set Rng = Range("AA2", Range("AA100000").End(xlUp))
For Each Prod In Rng
Set c = Range("C:C").Find(Prod.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
Tot = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
Ord = Application.SumIf(Range("C:C"), Prod.Value, Range("D:D"))
If Ord > Tot Then
For Each cell In Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
If cell.Value = Prod.Value Then
Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, 2)).Interior.Color = 65535
End If
Next cell
End If
Next Prod
Range("AA:AA").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Or if you choose without VBA, use Conditional Formatting.

1. Select the range you want to be highlighted
2. Click Conditional Formatting ---> New Rule
3. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Type `=SUMIF($C:$C,$C2,$D:$D)>VLOOKUP($C2,$C:$E,3,FALSE)` in the formula box
5. Click Format button, then do the formatting as you want
6. Click OK, Click OK.

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this. Assuming your table above starts on row 1 with Line in column A and TotalQty in column E; put a unique list of Product in column F and in cell G2 put the formula:

```
=IF(SUMIF(C:C,F2,D:D)>VLOOKUP(F2,C:E,3,FALSE), "Over", "Equal or under")
```

The `SUMIF` sums OrderQty for each Product, the `VLOOKUP` returns TotalQty for the first instance of each Product found in the table. You can then use conditional formatting to highlight rows if required.

If you did go the VBA route, I'd probably put the table into an array, create a dictionary of Product with a value for OrderQty, and either loop on the array and sum values, or loop on the dictionary keys and call the sumif worksheet function.

Answer (score 0):

[Good day Kyle,

Is this what you are trying to do. This is only simple solution but can help you.
I used a helping column for your criteria you mentioned. I used sumifs. You can modify it to your style and needs. I used conditional formatting to highlight cells.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMwKO.png)

Comment: You should consider updating your answer to be in line with the [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

First, streamline your table, divide into two tables:

1. line, customer, product, OrderQty in one table.
2. product, TotalQty other table.

Assuming {product,TotalQty} in 'Sheet 2', and the other table in 'Sheet 1', then add a column in second table (C column in sheet 2) 'OrderQty>TotalQty' and insert formula in the cell below it, as follows:

```
=IF(SUMIF(Sheet1!$C:$C,$A2,Sheet1!$D:$D)>$B2,"Yes","No")
```

Drag or copy-paste the formula to remaining product rows.

Screenshots:
[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]